# How can I use multiple inheritance to compose Django forms?

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance

I have lots of forms which contain the same non-model field. For the sake of this example, let's call the field `author`. This is not a field of any model, just a field that I want to appear in each form. Here is a working example of my current code:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class BlogForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Blog
        fields = ["author"]

class BookForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = models.Book
        fields = ["author"]
```

So, naturally, I thought I could use Python inheritance and create a reusable "mixin" class that contains this field. However, it seems that this is not possible. For some reason, I can't get the following to work:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class AuthorMixin:
    author = forms.CharField()

class BookForm(AuthorMixin, forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Book
        fields = ["author"]
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (author) specified for Book
```

How can I use multiple inheritance to compose Django forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AuthorMixin class should override forms.Forms:

```
class AuthorMixin(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField()

class BookForm(AuthorMixin, forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Book
        fields = ["author"]
```

Comment: While this would work, I am trying to compose new forms using multiple inheritance (hence the [Mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)). The reason for this is that I have already defined my own base class for forms and I wish to use the `AuthorMixin` for selected forms only.

Comment: You didn't specify that you would like to override from your own base class, in fact your example was that of using a mixin alongside an override of django Form class. I have updated the answer to reflect your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed!